# Windows 10, partitions and recovery

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have recently converted my boot drive to GPT and I have two questions.

1. There is ~2mb unallocated space right after the boot partition and ~1mb unallocated at the end of the partition table. Is this normal, because of GPT? That unallocated space only shows up on EaseUS Partition Master, but no other partition manager I've tried.
2. A recent Windows 10 update added a 450mb partition on my disk, which I checked and it contains the WinRE. Is that partition independent? I mean, even before the update I could normally reboot by holding shift and it would get me into the recovery menu, which still works. But if I try the `reagentc /info` command while booted into Windows, everything shows as disabled. Is this something I need to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I wouldn't worry about those two minor unallocated spaces that show in the third-party partition utility. It won't affect the performance or the system in any way.

2) This 450 MB partition is actually another recovery partition that appears with all Windows 10 updates. The setup in GPT mode basically creates 4 partitions:

a. The Windows partition,

b. a 100 MB EFI System Partition,

c. a 128 MB MS Reserved Partition

d. a 450 MB WinRe partition

Hope I was helpful. Best of luck! :)

Comment: Hey there thanks for the answer, let me add few pointers. 1) It just bugs the hell out of me, call it OCD :) and 2) I originally had an MBR installation and had manually moved the 100mb boot partition into the boot drive itself. After converting to GPT, I manually created a 200mb EFI partition to which i copied the bootsector and it worked fine. I have no idea what the 128mb partition is for in your example. So, should reagentc /info return enabled or not? I'm confused